# OpenGL doesn't draw my texture

Tags: opengl, textures, bmp, texture2d

My problem is that OpenGL 3.3 doesn't draw my texture. I checked if it a problem of my shader (It could not be loaded well) but the shader is OK. Then, I checked if it is a problem with UV coordinates, but I watched that it is OK using this code of Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec3 outColor;

in DATA {
    vec2 UV;
} fs_in;

void main() {
    outColor = vec3(fs_in.UV.x, fs_in.UV.y, 0.0);
}
```

Finally, I used this code of Fragment Shader but it doesn't work:

```
#version 330 core

out vec3 outColor;

uniform sampler2D mySampler;

in DATA {
    vec2 UV;
} fs_in;

void main() {
    outColor = texture(mySampler, fs_in.UV).rgb;
}
```

The code which loads a BMP image and gives it to OpenGL is the following (I found it on a website):

```
GLuint loadTexture(const char *lpszTexturePath) {
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned int dataPos;
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned int imageSize;
    unsigned char * data;

    FILE *file;

    fopen_s(&file, lpszTexturePath, "rb");

    if(!file)
        printf("Image could not be opened\n"); return 0;

    if(fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return false;
    }

    if(header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
    width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
    height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

    if(imageSize == 0)    imageSize = width*height * 3;
    if(dataPos == 0)      dataPos = 54;

    data = new unsigned char[imageSize];
    fread(data, 1, imageSize, file);

    fclose(file);

    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    return textureID;
}
```

Part of the main code:
GLuint uTextureID = loadTexture("image.bmp");

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(lpstWndID)) {
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(uProgID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTextureID);

    object.renderObject();

    glfwSwapBuffers(lpstWndID);
}
```

Comment: Did you step through the loading code in a debugger, and convince yourself that it was loading the BMP file successfully? With the expected sizes and everything?

Comment: The image was loaded correctly (I checked it)

Comment: Also, I tried to create a pixel array: 
'const char pixels[] = {
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
}'
but it doen't work

Comment: Do you somewhere tell the shader which texture to use (glUniform1i)?

Comment: It is only a texture. I never used what you say :S

Comment: @BDL The default value for uniform variables is 0. So as long as you use only one texture, and bind it to texture unit 0, things will work just fine without ever setting the uniform. I wouldn't consider it great style, but it's not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god. The mistake is very... very... Watch it by youself...

Line 10 of the texture loader:

```
if(!file)
        printf("Image could not be opened\n"); return 0;
```

Do anyone see something extrange? YEAH, IT HAS A RETURN 0 OUTSIDE OF THE IF BLOCK... This function was alwais returning 0...

Thanks (I'm stupid xD)

Comment: That doesn't help me. I've got your title-problem.